# Compare a value to an average value SQL

Tags: sql, average

I have a database with some persones stored in it, this persons have a residuallLave (holiday days they haven´t needed). Now I want to get the average value of this residualLeave and compare which persons have more than the average. But I get only one person back and this can't be true because there are more persons with a more residualLeave.

Code:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query won't work because you compare "normal" columns with aggregated ones without grouping. It is way simpler like this:

```
select *
from tpersons
where residualLeave > (select avg(residualLeave) from tpersons)
```

Comment: Thanks guys! I am quite new to SQL so just learning it.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here is a MySQL 8+ version using analytic functions:

```sql
SELECT persid, firstname, lastname, residualleave
FROM (SELECT *, AVG(residualleave) OVER () AS avgresidualleave FROM tpersons) t
WHERE residualleave > avgresidualleave;
```